# Findout future day, from any date in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a date of future such as:

```
 var date="01-12-15";
```

Now How can I know which day it is, i.e. it will be sunday/monday or ...in jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.getDay()` function of the `Date` object. It will return numbers from `0` to `6` meaning `sunday` to `saturday`.

Try

```
var date;
var xDayArray = ['sunday','monday','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat']    
var xdate= new Date(date);
alert(xDayArray[xdate.getDay()]);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ZrA5M/)

Comment: it returns 'Monday' for any date....such as 21/01/2014 it is today and is Tuesday but returnd 'monday', 22/01/2014 is wednesday, but returns 'Monday'......

Comment: var xDayArray = ['sunday','monday','tues','wed','thurs','fri','sat'];

 var xdate= new Date('date');
   var bar=xDayArray[xdate.getDay()];  
it returns undefined.....could you please findout what is wrong i am doing here?

Comment: @user3129375 Yeah that's it, its the globally supported format among all the browsers.

Comment: when I write this var dat = new Date("02/04/2014"); then it works fine but when I am writing var date; var dat = new Date('date'); then is is undefined. I need to use variable in Date();

Comment: @user3129375 Like this one.? http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ZrA5M/4/ Please let me know.

Comment: no. Like this one:  var date=document.getElementById('month_1').value+'/'+document.getElementById('date_1').value+'/'+document.getElementById('year_1').value;  
 var dat = new Date('date');
 var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
 var bar = days[dat.getDay()];

Comment: @user3129375 Can you make a fiddle of your code, so that i could help furtherly.

Comment: oh ..........get it.I should write like : var dat = new Date(date); Now it works. Thanks a lot @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @user3129375 Glad to help.! consider this answer as accepted if you wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var date = new Date("2015-12-01");
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var dayName = days[date.getDay()];
```

'getDay()' returns 0-based number. It must be converted to day name according to your language.

And you don't need jQuery to do it. Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Comment: What browser are you using? there's probably different issue, as this code works just fine. How do you use it?

Comment: I am using it as: var dat = new Date('date');
   var bar= dat.getDay();

Comment: Edited - date format was wrong for Mozilla Firefox. Now it works for both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @user3129375 it's ok now - string specifing the date wasn't x-browser - check my edited answer

Comment: thanks.....it works but when I write this var dat = new Date("02/04/2014"); then it works fine but when I am writing var date="01-12-15"; var dat = new Date('date'); then is is undefined. I need to use variable in Date();

Comment: if `date` must be variable then why you use apostrophes when passing this argument??